# Using stripe with Node

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Can you please help understand why sometimes while creating or updating a customer I see "card:" used and sometimes "source:". Both receives a token, but I can't get the difference.

2) I'm using node (and I've already seen the help page)
   Is this the correct way to create a token?

```
Stripe.card.createToken( {
                number : '4242424242424242',
                exp_month : '06',
                exp_year : '2016'
            }, function( s, response ) {
```

(I have the

```
var Stripe = require( 'stripe' )( 'sk_test....' );
```

)

I'm receiving "Cannot call method 'createToken' of undefined"

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 1):

I use it:

```
stripe.tokens.create({
   card: {
       number : '4242424242424242',
       exp_month : '06',
       exp_year : '2016'
   }
})
```